# How to retrieve the grails server login page on android emulator, is there any suggestion?

Tags: grails, android-emulator, spring-security

Sir,
I am new in android field so i am not able to retrieve the grails server login page on android emulator.
So please suggest me to overcome above said problem.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your locale Grails instance use the IP `10.0.2.2` in the Android emulator.

More info on [Android emulator network address](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).